# Is it possible to block only one hover message in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension, hover

when i hover over this fork button i get this message " fork your own copy of 'xyz' repo". i want it disabled. I am using a extension which shows another popup about the fork data of the repo , i want that to be enabled , hence i cant put a code to stop all the hover function of that button. i just want to add a code that blocks this particular hover message . how do it?[can i make that chart layer infront of the other message? or how to block that specific hover message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6C4P.png)

i tried disabling hover using pointer-events: none but it disabled all hover messages . i want one of them to stay

Comment: You can use a CSS rule: `tool-tip[for="fork-button"] { display: none; }`